# Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise not able to merge code using Git

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I am using VS 2015 RC and Git for version control but new version is having problem during the merging of code from one branch to another branch. 
Please let me know how to merge using VS2015 RC.

Comment: What is the problem you have?

Comment: Have you tried the RTM version of Visual Studio 2015? Does the error also occur when merging from the git command line?

Comment: In VS 2015 RC, when I click on "Resolve Conflict" option, it moves me merge window, where it shows all conflicted files, I select files one by one and merge the changes, but after merging files, Commit button still in disable mode. And I am not able to commit my merge files.                                            I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 RC.

Comment: I have no 'resolve conflict' link anywhere in my UI

Comment: Have you upgraded to VS 2015 official release? Do you still have this problem?

Comment: I have upgraged my VS 2015 to enterprise version. Now issues has been resolved.